# Laravel filter relationship field

Tags: laravel

I have a `users` table and `posts` table with `['title', 'body', 'user_id', 'id']` and have only one-to-one relation.

How can I filter the `posts` table showing only the `body` field using their relation.

e.g.

```
$users = User::with('post')->get();
```

and the result would be

```
[{
  'username':'jrsalunga',
  'post_id': 1,
  'post': {'title': 'sample title'}, // show title only 
  'id': 2
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also add a closure function in your with() like

```
    $users = User::with([
        'posts' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('title', 'user_id');
        }
    ])->get();
```

Remember to add the foreign key (user_id) or you will get a null values from the post relationship

Also, I think you need to change your relationship to one-to-many, like

User model

```
    public function posts()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

Post model

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongs('App\User');
    }
```

Comment: including the `foreign key (user_id)` works like charm! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you have to also select the `user_id` from the post, so this cannot be handled automatically by Eloquent.

---

Here's how you can map over them yourself:

```php
$users = User::with('post')->get()->map(function ($user) {
    $user = $user->toArray();

    $user['post'] = array_only($user['post'], 'title');

    return $user;
});
```